# The following _TypeError was thrown building Builder(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery]): type 'Future<Null>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

Context:

I am building a simple login app with azure ad, the app logins just fine and gets the token and redirects to the next page just fine, but before it redirects it throws an error

Error:

> The following _TypeError was thrown building Builder(dirty,
> dependencies: [MediaQuery]): type 'Future' is not a subtype of
> type 'Widget'
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    Builder
> file:///D:/Projects/flutter/aims_mobile/lib/screens/authentication/signin.dart:101:17
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      _SignInState.build. (package:aims_mobile/screens/authentication/signin.dart:133:25)
> #1      Builder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:7185:48)
> #2      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4749:28)
> #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:15)
> #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4369:5)

Code

```
class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  static const String SCOPE ='';
  static const String TENANT_ID = 'organizations';
  static String authority = "";

  MsalMobile msal;
  bool isSignedIn = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MsalMobile.create('assets/auth_config.json', authority).then((client) {
      setState(() {
        msal = client;
      });
      refreshSignedInStatus();
    });
  }

  /// Updates the signed in state
  refreshSignedInStatus() {
    msal.getSignedIn().then((loggedIn) {
      print('refreshing');
      setState(() {
        isSignedIn = loggedIn;
      });
    });
  }

  /// Signs a user in
  handleSignIn() async {
    await msal.signIn(null, [SCOPE]).then((result) {
      refreshSignedInStatus();
    }).catchError((exception) {
      if (exception is MsalMobileException) {
        logMsalMobileError(exception);
      } else {
        final ex = exception as Exception;
        print('exception occurred');
        print(ex.toString());
      }
    });
  }

  logMsalMobileError(MsalMobileException exception) {
    print('${exception.errorCode}: ${exception.message}');
    if (exception.innerException != null) {
      print(
          'inner exception = ${exception.innerException.errorCode}: ${exception.innerException.message}');
    }
  }

  /// Signs a user out.
  handleSignOut() async {
    try {
      print('signing out');
      await msal.signOut();
      print('signout done');
      refreshSignedInStatus();
    } on MsalMobileException catch (exception) {
      logMsalMobileError(exception);
    }
  }

  /// Gets the current and prior accounts.
  handleGetAccount() async {
    await msal.getAccount().then((result) {
      if (result.currentAccount != null) {
        print('current account id: ${result.currentAccount.id}');
        print('current account id: ${result.currentAccount.username}');
      } else {
        print('no account found');
      }
    }).catchError((exception) {
      if (exception is MsalMobileException) {
        logMsalMobileError(exception);
      } else {
        print('exception occurred');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Image.asset('assets/landing.webp',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.6),
                  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Container(
                  width: 130.0,
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        color: Color(0xffffffff),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            isSignedIn
                                ? Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => NavScreen()));
                                  })
                                : RaisedButton(
                                    child: Text("Sign In"),
                                    onPressed: handleSignIn,
                                  ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

I don't know how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a function `Future` instead of `Widget` which is causing this error.

```
isSignedIn
      ? Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {  // <---- This is not a widget
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NavScreen()));
        })
        : RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Sign In"),
        onPressed: handleSignIn,
    ),
```

Instead of doing this, you can use the `Visibility` widget to hide/show your "Sign In" button & using the `bool isSignedIn`, you can handle the navigation code.

```
Visibility(
  visible: !isSignedIn,
  child: RaisedButton(
    child: Text("Sign In"),
    onPressed: handleSignIn,
  ),
),
```

You should handle the navigation inside the `initState` method of your `StatefulWidget` which would look something like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  signInNavigation();
}

Future<void> signInNavigation() async {
  // isSignedIn = await yourMethodWhichReturnsSignInStatus(); <-- Replace this with your method

  if(isSignedIn) {
    // Your navigation code
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NavScreen()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ravi, thank you for you quick reply, I need to redirect to another page when signed is true, your implementation hides the button instead of loading the other page

Comment: I end up with the error  `Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null` after adding  `isSignedIn = await handleSignIn();`

Comment: Hi @Ravi no error but not redirecting to the other screen

Comment: Can you debug & check whether the navigation code is running in the `initState` method?

Comment: Hi Ravi, it is not being called for some wierd reason